# SSH into MySQL server and then from the server SSL into a database

Tags: mysql, ssl, ssh, openssh

I can SSH into a MySQL server. But how can I SSL into a database from the MySQL server to which I SSH'ed.

Comment: What do you mean "SSL into database"?

Comment: After SSH'ing into the server, how can I connect to a remote database through SSL by using the internal network where the server is hosted.

Comment: If you've already SSH'd into the server, why go out to the network again rather than just running `mysql`?

Comment: I'm trying to SSL into a cloud database.